# Nodemailer contact form is being hit by spambots submitting bogus data

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

Having issues with Spambots submitting bogus data to my nodemailer contact form from my express app which is live on a digital ocean droplet.

I tried setting up a hidden form field that redirects and prevents form submission but that does not seem to be working.

```
app.post("/products/contactCorporate", function (req, res) {
  let { name, email, message, businessAddress } = req.body;

  //businessAddress is a hidden field on my form
  if (businessAddress.length !== 0) {
    req.flash('success', 'Sorry Bot!');
    res.redirect("/products/contactCorporate");
  } else {
    submitForm();
  }
});
```

I would like to find an NPM package or solution to verify the email on the backend before form submission or trick the bot in some way. I would rather not use a captcha.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by verify the email?  Do you mean verify the email address that is being used?  Verify the message being sent?  Verify the business address?

Comment: I want to make sure the email is real and not a bot submission.

Comment: What are you defining as a real email?  Because I could make a bot that sends the email `John.Smith@gmail.com` but that could be a real email as well.  If you just want to check to make sure the email looks valid you can do that with regex but it won't be very robust.

Comment: I would define real email as not a bot. I guess I would just like to filter out the junk. I was able to do this in my past projects using PHP for form submission and creating a hidden honeypot field that would prevent the form from submitting if it contained data. It's weird too because I have other forms on the site, but only one of them seems to be getting spammed.

Comment: And the same logic doesn't work for Node + Express?  Have you gone through the code and checked to see what is happening?

Comment: Apparently not, since I have a honeypot set up and bot mail is still getting through. I just came across this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-email-hostname going to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done with the NPM package a [email-existence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-existence)

Existence is determined by telnetting to the MX server of the email domain and attempting to send an email to the supplied address. MX servers return 250 if the email address exists and 550 if it does not.

```
app.post("/products/contactCorporate", function (req, res) {
  let { name, email, message, businessAddress } = req.body;

  emailExistence.check(email, function (error, response) {
    if (response === false) {
      req.flash('success', 'Sorry, the email seems to be spam!');
      res.redirect("/products/contactCorporate");
    } else {
      submitForm();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Turns out email-existence is not the complete solution. I'm currently looking into [kickbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kickbox)